# Ableton Live / Osculator / TouchOSC: Send all values to remote control device

Tags: midi, ableton, ableton-live

I'm using TouchOSC on an iPad to remote control many values in an Ableton Live Project. To translate between OSC (TouchOSC) and MIDI (Ableton Live) I'm using OSCulator.

Now when I startup TouchOSC on the iPad, all controls are by default set to zero. What I would like is to make Ableton Live send ALL the correct values to the iPad, so that the controls are updated.

To be clear: Bidirectional communication works fine, when I change a value in Ableton Live, the iPad gets updated. But I would like to update ALL the controls at once using a script, tool, dark magic - whatever you guys can think of.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no way to do this using stock Ableton Live while a project is running.  However, I believe that Live sends out the positions of those controls when you first open a project, so if you can close and re-open the project, I think you can get the values where you want them.

It's a workaround rather than a proper solution, but short of some kind of crazy Max4Live patch I can't think of any way to transmit all of this information at once in Live.

Comment: You're right, Live does send all values on opening a project. That solves my issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
This is item on OSCulator forum that can help you to make work a tip with double "command M" it works with ableton live, perhaps it can help you to make it work with other programs !

http://www.osculator.net/forum/threads/1735-Fader-on-rotary-for-ableton-live-only-min-and-max?p=7871#post7871

Answer (score 1):

You can make a quick max for live patch that uses liveremote or liveobject to quickly scan through every possible parameter and send a "bang" to it (this would have the same effect as quickly touching all the knobs and sliders and buttons etc).

One of those max4live objects lets you scroll through controls by id or something like that so you just make a counter and metro that bangs every millisecond (you might have to go a tiny bit slower just so all your stuff doesn't crash at once) and just get it to find the current value of that slider/know/whatever and resend it to itself.

Erm, so you want to use liveobserver (I can't remember what it's called but it's something like that).  But the answer is that it's easy you just have to read about the max objects who's names start with live.(name) and are related to live.remote.

I wish I could remember what the names are so I wouldn't sound like such a space cadet but it's a lot easier than it may seem.  This approach also has the added bonus of teaching you a bit about the live.remote/object/observer/etc objects (if you don't already know about them) which is awesome, cause they're pretty darn cool.

:) good luck!

Comment: I cleaned this one up a bit, but I think it still needs some additional work.  Would someone who knows more about such things please edit this to make it clearer?